# jTab and ABCjs Formatting Sandbox

Tags: discussion, jtab, abcjs

Since we now have both jTab and ABCjs on active on the meta, it's time we had a specific place to test both. Use the answer space below to test and stretch the limits of both jTab and ABCjs for both on-site documentation of how each work and to find where there may be issues encountered.

Note: The formatting does not seem to kick in immediately when you save the changes. You need to re-load the page for the formatting to apply to the post.

Comment: Is this supposed to render on mobile? I only see the raw code

Comment: @Some_Guy to my knowledge it only renders on desktop

Answer (score 5):

Basic chord progression in jTab:

```
Cmaj7  Dm7 G7 Cmaj7
```

Not the most obvious changes on the fingers. Let's try try the barre forms:

```
%X/X.3/1.5/3.4/2.5/4.3/1[Cmaj7] %X/X.5/1.7/3.5/1.6/2.5/1[Dm7] %3/1.5/5.3/1.4/2.3/1.3/1[G7] %X/X.3/1.5/3.4/2.5/4.3/1[Cmaj7]
```

Not rendering quite right. Let's try one per line in a code block:

```
%X/X.3/1.5/3.4/2.5/4.3/1[Cmaj7]
%X/X.5/1.7/3.5/1.6/2.5/1[Dm7]
%3/1.5/5.3/1.4/2.3/1.3/1[G7]
%X/X.3/1.5/3.4/2.5/4.3/1[Cmaj7]
```

Not rendering quite right. Let's try one per code block:

```
%X/X.3/1.5/3.4/2.5/4.3/1[Cmaj7]
```

-

```
%X/X.5/1.7/3.5/1.6/2.5/1[Dm7]
```

-

```
%3/1.5/3.3/1.4/2.3/1.3/1[G7]
```

-

```
%X/X.3/1.5/3.4/2.5/4.3/1[Cmaj7]
```

That's pretty ugly. Let's get it fixed.

Comment: +1 Same problems I've run into in jTab.

Answer (score 2):

```
X: 1
M: 9/8
K: Cmaj
L: 1/8
"1"G"+"G"a"G GGG GGG|
```

```
X: 1
M: 3/4
K: Cmaj
L: 1/8
(3 GGG (3 GGG (3 GGG|
```

```
X: 1
M: 9/8
K: Cmaj
L: 1/8
G2G G2G G2G|
```

```
X: 1
M: 3/4
K: Cmaj
L: 1/8
(3 G-GG (3 G-GG (3 G-GG|
```

```
X: 1
M: 3/4
K: Cmaj
L: 1/8
(3:2:2 G2G (3:2:2 G2G (3:2:2 G2G
```

Answer (score 2):

```
X: 1
T: Symphony No. 7
C: Gustav Mahler (1860-1911)
R: Langsam (Adagio)
M: 4/4
L: 1/8
K: Bm
[F,^G,B,D]z/.[F,G,B,D]//.[F,G,B,D]// [F,G,B,D]z/.[F,G,B,D]//.[F,G,B,D]// !///![F,G,B,D]4 | [F,^G,B,D]z/[F,G,B,D]//[F,G,B,D]// [F,G,B,D]z/.[F,G,B,D]//.[F,G,B,D]// !///! [F,G,B,D]4 |
```

Another work

```
X: 1
T: The Alma Chord (Symphony No. 10)
C: Gustav Mahler (1860-1911)
R: Adagio
M: 4/4
L: 1/8
K: F#
%%staves {(RH) (LH)}
V: RH clef=treble
V: LH clef=bass
%
[V: RH] z4 z2 +p+  (^B,2 | +ff+ (G'8) | +diminuendo(+ (G'8) | +diminuendo)+ G'2>) F'2 E'2> D'2 | +pp+ [A,8 C8 A8] | A8 | +fermata+ A8 ||
[V: LH] z8 | z4 [(=B,,,4 (F,,4(=B,,4 (D,] | [(B,,,8) (F,,) (B,,) (D,)] | [B,,,8) F,,) B,,) D,)] | [F,,,6F,,6C,,6] [C,2G,2] | [F,,,6F,,6C,,6] [C,2G,2] | +invertedfermata+[F,,,8F,,8C,,8] ||
```

Another work

```
X: 1
T: Fresh
C: Kool & The Gang
R: 
M: 4/4
L: 1/8
K: Bm
%%staves {(RH) (LH)}
V: RH clef=treble
V: LH clef=bass
%
[V: RH] [D' =A']8 |
[V: LH] [F, ^A, C E]8 |
```

Another work

```
X: 1
T: Dmitri's Toyshop
C:
R: 
M: 2/4
L: 1/8
K: A
%%staves {(RH) (LH)}
V: RH clef=treble
V: LH clef=bass
%
[V: RH] z1 (_E/_A/).=C'.B | =A4 | z1 (_E/_A/).=C'.B | =A4 |
[V: LH] z4 | z2 [A,,E,][A,,E,] | [A,,E,] z1 z2 | z2 [A,,D,=F,][A,,D,F,] |
```

Another work

```
X: 1
T: Leading Tone Chords (from Symphony No. 6 "Páthetique")
C: Pyotr I. Tchaikovsky (1840-1893)
R: 
M: 4/4
L: 1/16
K: B
%%staves {(RH) (LH)}
V: RH clef=treble
V: LH clef=bass
%
[V: RH] z8 [C E G]7 [D F]1 | [D F]8 z8 |
[V: LH] z8 [C,E,A,]7 [D,B,]1 | [D,B,]8 z8 |
```

Answer (score 2):

```
X:0
K:Cmin
L:4
Q:"C minor ('native')"
[CFA]2 [=B,FG]2 [CEG]4 || [K:C] [Q:"C major (borrowed)"] \
[CF_A]2 [B,FG]2 [CEG]4 |]
s: iv V♮7 i iv V7 I
```

```
X:1
K:C major
M:3/4
L:1/8
CC CC CC
```

```
X:1
K:C major
M:3/4
L:1/8
""(3:2:2 ""A2A (3:2:2 A2A (3::2 A2A
```

```
storing code here while trying other stuff
|:G/2G/2 G/2G/2  G/2G/2  G/2G/2 ||  (3:3:2GG/2 (3:3:2GG/2 (3:3:2GG/2 (3:3:2GG/2 ||
```

```
X:0
T:bass clef test
K:C major bass
M:C
A,,B,,C,D,
```

#### Which decorations work?

```
X:2
T:Trying out !arpeggio!
M:4/4
L:1/2
K:Emin
!arpeggio![Begb]
```

```
X:1
T:All the decorations in the spec
M:4/4
L:1/2
K:Emin middle=b
.a~bHcLdMeOfPgSaTbucvd
!trill!a"_ext tr 1"!trill(!b"_ext tr 2"!trill)!b !lowermordent!c
!uppermordent!d !mordent!e !pralltriller!e !roll!f !turn!g "_turnx"!turnx!a
"_inv turn"!invertedturn!a "_inv turnx"!invertedturnx!b
!arpeggio![ace] !>!a !accent!b !emphasis!c !fermata!d !invertedfermata!e
!tenuto!f !0!g !1!e !2!f !3!a !4!b !5!c !+!d !plus!e !snap!f !slide!g
!wedge!a !upbow!b !downbow!c !open!d !thumb!e !breath!f !pppp!g !ppp!a !pp!b
!p!c !mp!d !mf!e !f!f !ff!g !fff!a !ffff!b !sfz!c !crescendo(!def!crescendo)!g
!<(!abcde!<)!f !diminuendo(!gabc!diminuendo)!d !>(!ef!>)!g !segno!a !coda!b
"_!D.S.!"c "_!D.C.!"d "_dacoda"e "_dacapo"f !fine!g
!shortphrase!y !mediumphrase!b !longphrase!c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
X:1
L:1/4
M:
K:F
V:1 clef=treble
"Gm"[g _b d] "Gb+"[_g _b d] "Bb/F"[f _b d ] "E7b5"[e ^g _b d]|"Gm"[g _b d] "Gb+"[_g _b d] "Bb/F"[f _b d ] "C7"[c e g _b]
%
```

Answer (score 1):

This is some ABC code

```
X: 1
M: C
K: Cmaj
L: 1/4
GGGG GGGG|
```

That was some ABC code

Answer (score 1):

```
X: 1
T: Kamouraska
K: none
M: 4/4
L: 1/16
%%staves {(RH) (LH)}
V: RH clef=treble
V: LH clef=bass
%
[V: RH] a3g- g2a2 e3d- d2c2 |
[V: LH] A,2E2C2E2 A,2E2C2E2 |
```

Answer (score 1):

### Options for Harmonics

##### Code

1. `!open!`
2. `0` (number zero)
3. `"o"` (small letter "o")
4. `"○"` (white circle: `U+25CB`, `&cir;`)
5. `"°"` (degree sign: `U+00B0`, `&deg;`)
6. `"  °"` (degree sign with 2 non-breaking spaces: `U+00A0`, `&nbsp;`)

##### Browser Render

```
X:1
L:1/4
K:C clef-treble-8
!open!e'|"0"e'|"o"e'|"○"e'|"°"e'|"  °"e'||
```

##### Image of Render

[image: Render of the above code: the first looks right; the second is too large and off centre; the third is too high, too small, and off centre;]

Comment: If your setup's browser is rendering the above significantly different, please add an image to this post.

Answer (score 1):

```
X: 1
T: Drum Kit
M: 
L: 1/4
K: C clef=perc
V: stem=down style=normal
"^hi-hat pedal"!style=x!D "^bass drum 2"E "^bass drum"F "^floor tom 2"G "^floor tom 1"A "^tom 3"B "^snare"c "^side stick"!style=x!c "^tom 2"d "^tom 1"e "^tom 0"f ||
[K: style=x]
"^ride"f "^ride bell"!style=normal!f "^hi-hat"g "^hi-hat open"!style=normal!g "^crash"a "^chinese"!style=harmonic!a "^crash 2"b "^splash"c' ||
```

```
X: 2
T: a little interruption
M: 4/4
L: 1/8
K: C clef=perc style=x
%%score (up down)
V: up stem=up 
gggg gg g!style=normal!c/!style=normal!c/ | aggg gggg ||
[K: style=normal]
V: down stem=down style=normal
[L: 1/4]
F c F c | F c F c ||
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem rendering LilyPond code with `\slurDashed`

(See: [LilyPond - opacity of objects (slurs specifically)](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/131630/lilypond-opacity-of-objects-slurs-specifically))

---

Wrapping `c` with code fences (```` ``` ```` & ```` ``` ````):

```
c
```

*Pass*

---

Wrapping `\slurDashed c` with code fences (```` ``` ```` & ```` ``` ````):

```
\slurDashed
c
```

*Fail* — Looks find in the editor, and looks fine when first posted, but does not render upon a reload of the page.

---

Wrapping `\slurDashed c` with code fences and LilyPond language hint (```` ```lilypond ```` & ```` ``` ````):

```
\slurDashed
c
```

*Fail* — Same as above

---

Wrapping `\slurDashed c` with code fences and Plaintext language hint (```` ```plaintext ```` & ```` ``` ````):

```
\slurDashed
c
```

*Fail* — Same as above

---

Wrapping `\slurDashed c` with HTML preformatted text tags (`<pre>` & `</pre>`):

```
\slurDashed
c
```

*Pass*

---

It looks like the `\slurDashed` command is trigging jTab or ABCjs (or something else).

Comment: lilypod isn't rendered only jtab and abcjs. my guess is the second line is triggering jtab somehow.

Comment: @Dom I think I've isolated to problem to the command `\slurDashed`, but I'm not sure why this is causing issues; I can't find anything like it in the jTab or ABCjs documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to ask about beaming, but if you put a space between the two groups of four Gs then it gets beamed as two groups of four quavers.

```
X: 1
M: C
K: Cmaj
L: 1/8
|GGGG GGGG|
```

I've also added the quote without the first barline.

```
X: 1
M: C
K: Cmaj
L: 1/8
GGGG GGGG|
```

Comment: Take the first bar off in your line of notes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious about how big of a score we can use. Let's see:

```
X: 1
M: C
K: Cmaj
L: 1/8
CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|
CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|
CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|
CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|
```

... 50 lines more (deleted again because it made the page load really slow) ...

```
X: 1
M: C
K: Cmaj
L: 1/8
CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|
CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|
CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|CDE^F ^G^FED|
```

**Do not click the edit history** (at least not with JavaScript enabled); it'll clog down your browser.

Comment: It's good you tried that, but as you noticed, such a long score makes the page load really slow, even in the version with “only” 57 lines. I removed most of them.

Comment: MUST PUSH BUTTON!

Answer (score 0):

```
X: 1
L: 1/8
K: Cmaj
M: C
%% score (D1 D2)
V:D1 clef=perc
V:D2 clef=perc
% 1
[V:D1] ffff  ffff
[V:D2] E2 B2 E E B2
```

...

```
X:1
L:1/8
M:C
K:Am
%%score (T1 T2) (B1)
V:T1           clef=treble
V:T2           clef=treble
V:B1           clef=bass
% 1
[V:T1] (d8            d2 )
[V:T2] A,2dc   BA"⚡"GF E2
[V:B1] G,2^F,E,F,2^G,2 A,2
```

...

```
X:1
L:1/2
M:
K:C
%%score (T1 T2) (B1 B2)
V:T1           clef=treble
V:T2           clef=treble
V:B1           clef=bass
V:B2           clef=bass
% 1
[V:T1] _A, B,  (F    G)
[V:T2] F,  _A,  B,   B,
[V:B1] D,  F,  _A,  _A,
[V:B2] B,, D,  D,   D,
```

...

```
X:1
L:1/8
M:2/2
K:C
%%score T1 T2 A B
V:T1           clef=treble
V:T2           clef=treble
V:A            clef=alto
V:B            clef=bass
% 1
[V:T1] cd cB A2 "First"G2 | "cadence"c4       zB cd | ef ed f2 "Once"g2   | "more"c'4
[V:T2] G2 A2 F2  F2 | E4       G2 AB | cd cB c2 B2   | c4
[V:A]  EF ED C2  B,2| C2  CD   E2 F2 | G2 A2 F2 "Extra"_A2  | "tension"G4
[V:B]  C4    F,2 G,2| zG, A,B, C3  G,| C,4  A,,2 D,2 | E,2 C,2
```

...

```
X: 1
M: 9/8
K: Cmaj
L: 1/8
V:C name="Cello" clef=bass
(!0!C,,!3!E,,!0!G,, !4!C,!3!E,!1!G, !thumb!C!2!E!thumb!G) | (!3!c!thumb!G!1!E !4!C!1!G,!4!E, !1!C,!0!G,,!3!E,,) | !0!C,,6
```

...

```
X:1
L:1/4
M:
K:F
V:2 clef=treble
"bVII"[_E G =B]4|    !0!d''3
%
```

...

```
X:1
L:1/32
M:5/4
K:Am
V:H     name="Harp 1"    clef=treble
z8  (7 ^f,^g,a,^c^f^g^a (7 ^c'agfca,g, (7 f,g,a,cfga (7 c'agfca,g, (7 f,g,a,cfga (7 c'agfca,g, (7 f,g,a,cfga (7 c'agfca,g, |
"F♮ C♮"z8  (7 _b,cdf_bc'd' (7f'd'c'bfdc (7 b,cdfbc'd' (7f'd'c'bfdc (7 b,cdfbc'd' (7f'd'c'bfdc (7 b,cdfbc'd' (7f'd'c'bfdc
```

...

```
X:1
L:1/4
M:
K:F
V:2 clef=treble-8
c2
%
```

...

```
X:1
L:1/16
M:C
K:C
V:2 clef=perc
f,4 z3 f, f,4 z4
%
```

...

```
X:1
T:The Athole Highlanders
L:1/16
M:6/8
K:D
V:2 clef=treble
|: A6 A3FD2 | A3FD2 E3FG2 | A6 A3FD2 | E3FG2 F3ED2 |
A6 A3FD2 | A3FD2 E3FG2 | Ad3A2 B3AG2 | F3GE2 D6 :|
%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X:1
L:1/4
M:
K:C
V:1 clef=treble
"I"[C E G] "bVI"[_A C _E] "IV"[F A C] "V7"[G B D F]
%
```

---

```
X:1
L:1/1
M:
K:C
V:1 clef=treble
""[C D] | ""[D c]
%
```

---

```
X:1
L:1/4
M:
K:C
V:1 clef=treble
"I"[C E G] "bVI"[_A C _E] "IV"[F A C] "V7"[G B D F]
%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X:1
L:1/4
M:
K:C Minor
V:1 clef=treble
"i7(Cm7)"[C _E G _B] "tt(Eb7)"[_E G _B _d] "(V/V)D7"[D ^F A c] "tt(Eb7)"[_A c _e _g] | "V7(G7)"4[G B d f]||
%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X:2
L:1/2
M:
K:C
V:1 clef=treble
(!tenuto!c  .c)
%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X:1
R: Syncopated
M:C
K:C
L: 1/4
z/2 B c (B/2 | B/2) A/2 B c2 |]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%X.X.X.XX.6/3.4/1 %X.4/2.3/1.4/3.4/3.6/4[Db13]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X:1
M:2/4
K:C
L:1/4
c/2 c/2 c/2 c/2 | c c |
```

and

```
X:2
M:2/4
K:C
L:1/4
c c/2 c/2 | z c |
```

and

```
X:3
M:2/4
K:C
L:1/4
c/2 c/2 c | c z |
```

and

```
X:4
M:2/4
K:C
L:1/4
c/2 c c/2 | c2 |
```

and

```
X:5
M:2/4
K:C
L:1/4
c c | z2 |
```

and

```
X:6
M:10/4
K:C
L:1/4
c/2 c c c/2 c/2c/2 c c c/2 c c/2 c | c3 c z2 c2 z |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X: 1
M:4/4 
L: 1/1
K: C
%%staves {(RH) (LH)}
V: RH clef=treble
V: LH clef=bass
%
[V: RH] [A ^C E] | [_A C F] 
[V: LH] [F, _A, C,] | [_E, _G, _B,,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Allignment of chords is weird, the note first note of each bar seems to be centred on the chord name which can make the notes in the bar end up off.  Also, no superscripts for numbers

for the sake of argument:

```
X: 1
L: 1/4
K: Cm clef=treble-8
|"C-"E2 G,2|"Eb7" C3 E |"D7" D2 =A,2|C3 D |"Ab-6susXYZb17" E1/8 E1/8 E1/8 E1/8 E1/8 E1/8 E1/8 E1/8 E  _A,2|
```

Answer (score 0):

Fig.1

```
X: 1
K: D  
L: 1/4
%%score (T1 T2)
V:T1 clef=treble
V:T2 clef=treble
[V:T1] d d "app"^d//e3/4 "app"^e//f3/4
[V:T2] D D C D
```

Fig.2

```
X: 2
K: D  
L: 1/4
%%score (T1 T2)
V:T1 clef=treble
V:T2 clef=treble
[V:T1] d//f3/4 f//a3/4 a//d'3/4 d'//f'3/4
[V:T2] D D F D
```

Fig.3

```
X: 3
K: D  
L: 1/4
%%score (T1 T2)
V:T1 clef=treble
V:T2 clef=treble
[V:T1] d d "app"^d3/4e// "app"^e3/4f//
[V:T2] D D C D
```

Fig.4

```
X: 4
K: D  
L: 1/4
%%score (T1 T2)
V:T1 clef=treble
V:T2 clef=treble
[V:T1] d d3/4^d// e3/4^e// f
[V:T2] D D C D
```

Fig.5

```
X: 5
K: Gm
L: 1/4
%%staves {(RH) (LH)}
V: RH clef=treble
V: LH clef=bass
%
[V: RH] "5th"d/2"nt"c/2 "5th"d/2"nt"c/2 | "app"d/2"5th"c/2 "app"d/2"5th"c/2 | "3rd"d2 |
[V: LH] "i"[G,2B,2D2] |"V7/III"[F,2A,2C2E2] |"III"[B,,2F,2B,2D2]|
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X: 1
M: 4/4 
L: 1/1
K: C
%%staves {(RH) (LH)}
V: RH clef=treble
V: LH clef=bass
%
[V: RH] "C13"[D F A] | "C13♯11"[D ^F A] 
[V: LH] [C, E, G, _B,] | [C, E, G, _B,]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X:1
T:Test
M:C|
L:1/8
K:G
GABc dedB & [G,4B,4D4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox for answer to another question

C#min to B

```
Cm:2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox for answer to another question

C#min to B

```
%X/X.3/1.5/3.4/2.5/4.3/1[C#maj7]
```

-

```
%X/X.3/1.3/4.2/1.5/4.3/1[C#maj7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a test

```
%2.0.0.X.X.X[C#maj7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Formatting ABC

```
X:1
K:Em
L:1/4
E
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X: 1
K: C  
L: 1/4
%%score (T1 T2)
V:T1 clef=treble
V:T2 clef=treble
[V:T1] C D E F | G A B c
[V:T2] "1st"C "2nd"C "3rd"C "4th"C | "5th"C "6th"C "7th"C "8th"C
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X: 1  
K: C
M: 1/4  
L: 1/4   
[_B,_E] [CF] [_E_A] [F_B] [_Ac] | [_B_e] [cf] [_e_a] [f_b] |
```

```
X: 1
T: Cooley's
M: 4/4
L: 1/8
R: reel
K: Emin
|:D2|EB{c}BA B2 EB|~B2 AB dBAG|FDAD BDAD|FDAD dAFD|
EBBA B2 EB|B2 AB defg|afe^c dBAF|DEFD E2:|
|:gf|eB B2 efge|eB B2 gedB|A2 FA DAFA|A2 FA defg|
eB B2 eBgB|eB B2 defg|afe^c dBAF|DEFD E2:|
```

```
X: 1
T: Cooley's
M: 4/4
L: 1/8
K: Emin
|:D2|"Em"EBBA B2 EB|\
    ~B2 AB dBAG|\
    "D"FDAD BDAD|\
    FDAD dAFD|
"Em"EBBA B2 EB|\
    B2 AB defg|\
    "D"afe^c dBAF|\
    "Em"DEFD E2:|
|:gf|"Em"eB B2 efge|\
    eB B2 gedB|\
    "D"A2 FA DAFA|\
    A2 FA defg|
"Em"eB B2 eBgB|\
    eB B2 defg|\
    "D"afe^c dBAF|\
    "Em"DEFD E2:|
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha!

```
X: 1
M: 4/4
L: 1/4
K: Emin
%% score (V1 V2)
V:V1
V:V2 merge
% 1
[V:V1]c-|cB2A|B4|B4
[V:V2]E|D2C2|B,2C2|B,2C2|
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X:1
M:3/4
L:1/8
K:none
B2 (3:2:2 G2F (3:2:2 G2A |
(3:2:2 B2A (3:2:2 B2G (3:2:2 E2D
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X:1
T:Speed the Plough
M:4/4
C:Trad.
K:G
|:GABc dedB|dedB dedB|c2ec B2dB|c2A2 A2BA|
  GABc dedB|dedB dedB|c2ec B2dB|A2F2 G4:|
|:g2gf gdBd|g2f2 e2d2|c2ec B2dB|c2A2 A2df|
  g2gf g2Bd|g2f2 e2d2|c2ec B2dB|A2F2 G4:|
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X: 1
K: D
L: 1/4
D/2 | G/2G/2 G>A B/2c/2 | e/2d/2- d2 g/2f/2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X: 1
K:Cb
L:8
M:6/8
(b2 e'2)(b2 | e'2)(b2 e'2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X: 1
K: C
L: 1/4
M:4/4
EEFG | GFED | CCDE | E>D D2
```

```
X: 1
K:C
L:1/4
M:4/4
Q:1/4 = 120
A A A A |\
M:7/8
A/2A/2 A/2A/2 A/2A/2 A/2
```

```
X: 1
K:C
L:1/4
M:2/2
Q:1/2 = 60
A A A A
```

```
X:1
L:1/2
K:A
[Ace] [Gce] | [FAc] [EAc]
```

Comment: Trying out html code for accidentals. ♭  %E2%99%AD &#9837;

Answer (score 0):

Testing simple exercise

```
X: 1
K: C
L: 1/4
    
[M: 4/4]||:!>!CCCC|!>!DDDD|!>!EEEE|!>!FFFF|!>!GGGG|!>!FFFF|!>!EEEE|!>!DDDD:||
[]
[M: 3/4]||:!>!CCC|!>!DDD|!>!EEE|!>!FFF|!>!GGG|!>!FFF|!>!EEE|!>!DDD:||
[]
[M: 2/4]||:!>!CC|!>!DD|!>!EE|!>!FF|!>!GG|!>!FF|!>!EE|!>!DD:||
```

Answer (score 0):

test

```
X: 0
K: C
L: 1/4

_B, C _D _E F G A _B
C _D _E F G A _B c
```

something wrong?

```
X: 1
K: C
L: 1/4

_G _A __B _c _d _e f _g
_A __B _c _d _e f _g _a
```

why not?

```
X: 2
K: C
L: 1/4

^G A B ^c ^d ^e ^f ^g
A B ^c ^d ^e ^f ^g a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X:1
L:1/8
M:4/4
K:C
V:1 clef=treble
cdec f3 d | BcdB e3 c | ABcA d3 B | ^GABG A4 ||
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X:1
M:4/4
K:C
|"C"C2D2E2F2|G2A2B2c2
|"F"d2c2B2A2|G2F2E2D2|"C"C8|
```

```
X:1
M:4/4
K:C
|"C"C2D2E2F2|G2F2E2G2
|"F"F2G2A2_B2|c2_B2A2F2|"C"C8|
```

```
X:1
M:4/4
K:C
|C2D2E2F2|G2F2E2G2|
```