# jTab doesn't render more than one Custom Chord per code block

Tags: bug, jtab

Testing [jTab on the meta](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2582/7222), I noticed that custom chords do not render if there is more than one in a code block.

The test set of chords I used this:

```
%X/X.3/1.5/3.4/2.5/4.3/1[Cmaj7] %X/X.5/1.7/3.5/1.6/2.5/1[Dm7] %3/1.5/5.3/1.4/2.3/1.3/1[G7] %X/X.3/1.5/3.4/2.5/4.3/1[Cmaj7]
```

On the jTab website it renders the following way which is much more desired:

[image]

Comment: As can be seen in @Dom's answer above, jTab is opaque when entry isn't what it expects. Please add submission format-checking and red balloon error messages--with descriptive error messages, please