# Why won't my jTab chord diagrams render side-by-side?

Tags: feature-request, bug, jtab

I just finished adding some chord diagrams [to an answer of mine](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/66374/39614) using jTab. I wanted to see three or four chord diagrams side-by-side, and my custom chord syntax was rendering nicely [on the jTab page](http://jtab.tardate.com/). But the best I could do here (after much trial and error) was to get two diagrams rendering side-by-side by separating pairs of chords with `<div></div>` tags.

I see [here](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2583/jtab-doesnt-render-more-than-one-custom-chord-per-code-block) and [here](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2581/jtab-and-abcjs-formatting-sandbox) that I am not the first person to have this sort of trouble.

Additionally, it was torture trying to get these diagrams right without any sort of preview (and the tablature diagrams were even more torturous). [This issue has also been raised before](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396/jtab-needs-to-render-in-markdown-preview).

Despite the fact that others have noticed these problems, and that the ability to add high-quality tablature and chord diagrams to posts seems extremely useful, I don't see very much discussion on Meta about it. Can we expect the buggy rendering to improve, and can we expect jTab rendering in Markdown previews any time soon, or is this feature just not used widely enough to merit any more development?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2583/jtab-doesnt-render-more-than-one-custom-chord-per-code-block