# Should ABC code blocks be limited to a certain length before rendering by ABCjs?

Tags: discussion, abcjs

I'm finding the "jTab and ABCjs Formatting Sandbox" is taking up to 20 seconds to render fully, and it seems to be because of [this post](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2590/12961), which is testing a particularly long block of ABC.

I'm on an old, low spec office PC running a bunch of applications at once, so not exactly giving poor ABCjs a chance. Nonetheless, if the amount of ABC code on a page is unlimited, then the potential is there to grind any browser to a halt, whether inadvertently or maliciously.

Assuming it's possible to do so, should any ABC be truncated to a certain limit before passing to the javascript, or is there a better way to address this problem?

*UPDATE - 
I copied Dom's ABC from the sandbox post, made it three times as long and posted it as an answer here. The page took 2 minutes to render. I doubt this will generally be an issue as people are most likely to use ABC for posting short musical snippet - more likely to be a problem if someone decides to be a nuisance. Maybe another way to go would be restricting access to this functionality to users with a certain amount of rep?

*UPDATE 2 -
Apologies to any mods looking at the revision history of my deleted answer. Nothing worth seeing, but if you do, disable javascript first, or else be prepared to wait!

Comment: It use to take minutes. I trimmed  it down a bunch.

Comment: Dom - perhaps worth removing that test post after the CM's are made aware of it. They may have a solution - such as Bacs' idea